# why do programmers use configureCell:atIndexPath: method to config the tableView Cell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

Well till a couple of days back I use to code everything for `UITableViewCell` in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method. But recently I found out that the iPhone developers (or mac) use `configureCell:atIndexPath:` and even most of the apples provided source code have this as one of the class function. **So my question is basically why do we like to create one more function to provide the cell contents then just write the whole code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method instead.**

PS. for people who are not familiar with this then you should see apples source code. and `configureCell:atIndexPath:` is not another method in UITableViewDatasource, its just a class function that we have in every class that has table view . And we use it like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
}
```

And more important, after just using this style for trial purpose I got in love this function and now I use it all the time.(When I am using a UITableView)

**Edit: Ok I think people are getting a wrong idea about my question so let me make it more clear.**

I meant why to create another function when you can place all your code in this function

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I am not concern about the method name.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It's done because you may want to update cells when they're already on the screen.  Rather than completely refreshing the cell, you can simply fetch the existing cell from the table view and run it through `configureCell:atIndexPath:`. If the method is correctly implemented, this will update all the data in the cell without having UITableView remove the old cell, dequeue or allocate the new cell, and put it on screen.

---

For historical interest:

As far as I know, I'm the guy who's responsible for `configureCell:atIndexPath:`.  I'm sure other people have come up with the same idea, but I believe the snippet of code that popularized it was originally written by me.  It was then spread by Apple and became a convention.

The early versions of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` had a `controllerDidChangeContent:` method, but no `controllerWillChangeContent:` call, which meant there was no opportunity to call `-[UITableView beginUpdates]` before changing the contents of the table view.

I filed Radar #6708453 asking for them to add this delegate method, and included some example code to show them what I wanted to do.  That code had the actual cell updating logic in a `refreshCell:atIndexPath:` call, so that it could be called from both `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:`.

When the next beta seed came out, I found that the iOS engineering team not only added the method I suggested, but copied the sample code from my bug report into the [NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), although they wisely changed the name to the less confusing `configureCell:atIndexPath:`.

I actually started a new project today with the Master/Detail iOS Core Data template, and noticed that my code—and the `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method with it—was in the template.  I ran a quick Google search to see if it had become a common convention.  It seems that it has.  I'm rather proud of what that little chunk of code has made of itself!

Comment: That is really a good piece of code snippet you have made. thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @Robin: You should probably accept this answer instead.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for the suggestion, but you answer is also close to this one. :)

Comment: Isn't there a potential bug with the `configureCell:atIndexPath:` approach is if the same set of updates reorders the table in a way such that the `indexPath` does not return the correct object for the cell? http://oleb.net/blog/2013/02/nsfetchedresultscontroller-documentation-bug/

Answer (score 10):

The only time that I've seen a real advantage, readability wise, is when you have multiple cell types. Then you can have separate methods that only know how to populate that particular cell type, like if you had 3 different cell types, for Dogs, Cats and Giraffes:

```
- (void)configureDogCell:(DogCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)configureCatCell:(CatCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void)configureGiraffeCell:(GiraffeCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

That said, I don't use this pattern myself. I've just seen it used by other developers in projects that I've worked on.

Answer (score 8):

Probably because we think customizing the properties and content of a cell belongs in a separate procedure from looking for a reusable cell to dequeue, and/or making a new one if there's nothing to dequeue.

Answer (score 6):

```
[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

it is simply just there to make your code clean and easy to read.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

you can call it anything but the majority choose to call it this way. This is because this method got pass in UITableViewCell object and indexPath object then it return the "configed" UITableViewCell which is then get return as a return object for

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in otherword, you can use

```
- (void)configureCellXXX:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and call it using

```
 [self configureCellXXX:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
```

and it would still work :)