# cellForRowAtIndexPath: Is it XCode template correct?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

This question is about cellForRowAtIndexPath.

As I know the correct way is

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
return cell;
```

But when I created Master-Detail template, code looks like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
 [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
 return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 NSManagedObject *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.textLabel.text = [[object valueForKey:@"timeStamp"] description];
}
```

**EDIT**: The question is not about configureCell atIndexPath. As you see these strings absent in XCode template.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault      reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] ;
```

Is XCode template correct?

Comment: Check this ,it will give you answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467831/why-do-programmers-use-configurecellatindexpath-method-to-config-the-tableview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template code is correct.

Beginning with iOS 5.0 it's possible to register a nib for a cell identifier. Whenever the table needs a cell and there are no reusable cells left it instantiates the nib and creates the cell by itself.

If you do so `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` always returns a cell; you don't have to create it yourself.

The API to register nibs is: [`registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW76).